# Who actually drafts the Queen's speech, in the present era?

Tags: united-kingdom, monarchy

I gather that over the years the level of realistic personal agency of the British monarch has actually waxed and waned a fair bit, and suspect that in recent eras it has progressively diminished to realistically next to nothing in terms of  power if not of wealth.

So whose prerogative and agency and agenda is the Queen's speech realistically an expression of in our current times?

Comment: The queen has essentially no hard power whatsoever. On paper, she does all sorts of things "at the advice of ministers," but this "advice" should be understood as a euphemism for "very politely-worded orders." She does have a fair amount of soft power; the PM has a private meeting with her on a weekly basis, and she's been on the throne for longer than most politicians have been alive, so they would be very foolish to ignore her altogether.

Comment: Does 'recent eras' mean 'since 1688'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey We Brits like to behead a monarch now and then, keeps the rest on their toes

Comment: @RedSonja  Yes, the latest was in 1649, although I don't remember it personally (I am old, but not quite that old). We get rid of them in a more genteel fashion these days, like in 1936.

Answer (score 3):

The Queen's Speech is written by the government.

> It sets out the government's legislative agenda for the new parliamentary session.  [Source](https://www.parliament.uk/business/news/2022/may-2022/lords-debates-queens-speech-2022/)

Comment: I'm sorry that I just say this is a most, albeit uncharacteristically, unsatisfying answer.

Comment: I agree, in my opinion this doesn't really rise to the level of a good *Stack Exchange* answer post, yet... can you address "Who actually drafts...?" and/or "...whose prerogative and agency and agenda...?" a bit further? Arguably those are not exactly the same thing at all, but can you at least choose one and go a little bit further? I'm also interested in finding out. *Thanks!*

Comment: It may be boring but it's the right answer. Actually with a bit of Google-fu OP could have found this out anyway. But it's a valid and interesting question.

Comment: The government in various ways employs an awful lot of people, including professional civil servants, political workers, and politicians. It would certainly be useful to explain in more detail who writes the speech. It is reasonably well-known which individuals wrote a particular party manifesto. So it doesn't seem unreasonable to ask which individuals are largely involved in drafting a particular speech, and a fortiori which department or office within the government is primarily involved (e.g. Leader of the House of Commons schedules parliamentary business, so might they be involved?).

Comment: Even if it's unknown or a secret, that would be a useful fact to know.